# glReadPixels fails under WebGL2 in Chrome on Mac

Tags: google-chrome, webgl2

I have this simple matmul code written for WebGL 2. This code and parameters run with no issues in Chrome on Windows. However, I consistently get this error in Chrome on Mac when I use `webgl2` context ID.

```
GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glReadPixels: format and type incompatible with the current read framebuffer
```

These are the parameters I use:

```
readOutput(gl, width, height, gl.RED, gl.FLOAT, c);
...
function readOutput(gl, width, height, format, type, buffer) {
  gl.readPixels(0, 0, width, height, format, type, buffer);
}
```

and this is how I created the texture:

```
const texA = createTexture(gl, gl.R32F, gl.RED, gl.FLOAT, shapeA[1], shapeA[0], a);
```

and finally here's the code for createTexture:

```
function createTexture(gl, internalFormat, format, type, width, height, data) {
  // Create the texture
  const texture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texImage2D(
    gl.TEXTURE_2D,
    0,  // 0 - no mipmaps
    internalFormat, width, height,
    0,  // Always 0 in OpenGL ES.
    format, type, data);
  checkError(gl);
  return texture;
}
```

Comment: So at the moment both browsers seem to support reading with RGBA/FLOAT instead of RED/FLOAT but both browsers [appear to be buggy](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/WebGL/issues/2747)

Comment: Thanks very @gman.
By the 2nd browser do you mean Safari?

Comment: Only 2 browsers support WebGL2, Chrome and Firefox. Safari has never supported WebGL2 and likely never will. There's a flag to enable it but if you look in the WebKit source there is absolutely no code for it and nothing new has been added in over 2 years, at least as of Dec-2018

Comment: Thanks a lot for the additional info.